# Injecting field values into sql queries in node

Tags: sql, node.js, sql-update, sql-injection

I am running a sql query in node that goes:

```
connection.query(`update foodplan set ? = ? where id = ?;`, [meal, favouriteChoice, idValue],
        function (err) {
            if (err) throw err;
            else console.log('Successful update');
        });
```

The value meal can either be 'breakfast', 'lunch' or 'dinner' - and these are 3 field values in the foodplan table. When this is run however, I get the following error:

"Error: You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right syntax to use near ''dinner' = 'wraps' where id = '24'' at line 1"

Anyone know what's wrong?

Comment: seems like the query can't get column name as dinner

Comment: it is definitely a column name within the table though - is there any way to make this work without having to write separate queries to insert into breakfast, lunch and dinner?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Query parameters are not simply another way to do string-substitutions. The parameter placeholder `?` is left as a placeholder until after the SQL is parsed. The SQL engine just remembers, "oh, there's going to be a value supplied here."

That's why it works as a fix for SQL injection — no matter what you eventually pass as the value for the parameter, the SQL engine will not treat it as anything but a single value.

NOT a column name, not any other kind of identifier, not an expression, not an SQL keyword, etc.

But for this reason, you cannot use a parameter in place of a column name. Only in place of a single value.

You must spell out all SQL syntax, expressions, identifiers, etc. **before** the SQL is parsed. Otherwise there's no way for the parser to validate your syntax, confirm that a column by that name exists, and that you have privilege to query that column.

Sorry, but you must put the column name into the query string, you cannot make it a parameter.

So you ask:

> is there any way to make this work without having to write separate queries to insert into breakfast, lunch and dinner?

It's safe to use string-concatenation to form an SQL query *if* the strings are guaranteed to be safe. In this case, you could make sure the column names breakfast, lunch, and dinner are whitelisted and under the control of your code, and do not allow any untrusted input to be used.